# How to parse group pattern in PHP like $1,$2 in Perl?

Tags: php, regex

I am C++/perl programmer and learning PHP and parsing text as follows.

```
$regex = "/AAL=(\w+)/";
$input_string = "AAL=data;AC=2;";
if (preg_match_all($regex, $input_string, $matches_out))
{
   echo $matches_out[0][0],"\n";
}
```

Output:

```
AAL=data
```

But how can i print only **data** like i use $1 for printing the pattern within bracket in Perl.

Comment: `$matches_out[1][0]` ?! Do `print_r($matches_out);` and you will see the structure of the array

Answer (score 1):

Just change the index number of  multidimensional array.

```
$regex = "/AAL=(\w+)/";
$input_string = "AAL=data;AC=2;";
if (preg_match_all($regex, $input_string, $matches_out))
{
   echo $matches_out[1][0],"\n";
}
```

Index 1 contains the value of first captured group.

```
    $matches_out[1][0]
                 ^  ^
  Refers the first  Refers the first value present inside the first captured group. 
  captured group
```

ie, if the input is `AAL=data;AC=2;AAL=[]`, `$matches_out[1][0]` contains `data` and `$matches_out[1][1]` contains `[]`.